# Transparent navbar over background image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have my hero/background image lay behind a transparent Bootstrap 4 navbar. Some suggestions have been to apply the background image to the  of the page, which works, but I do not want the background image on all of the other static pages inside my application...only the landing page (Rails application).

I've tried using negative margins on the navbar and/or container that holds the background image but everything so far has come with negative side-effects.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, even with the particular navbar I've chosen to use from Bootstrap, but I'm not having much luck.

**UPDATE:**

changing the navbar classes from:
`<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">`
to:
`<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">`
achieved exactly what I was looking for.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.bgimg {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473923377535-0002805f57e8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d239ac0e409e18cf74ace503c491714f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid bgimg"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use fixed navbar? https://jsfiddle.net/mgys77se/

Comment: The *beta* version of Bootstrap 4 is now really starting to get **outdated**...

Comment: @ZimSystem Oh geez...that was simple.  Yeah, it works, but in Bootstrap 4 it's just `fixed-top` instead of `navbar-fixed-top` I believe. I updated my question to have the most current CDN.  Thank you.

Comment: @WebDevBooster  Gotcha... I updated that.  Thank you.

Comment: `navbar-toggleable-` will also need to be replaced with `navbar-expand-`

Comment: @WebDevBooster  Brilliant.  I was just going through everything to see how adding the fixed-top class will effect everything else.  Adding `navbar-expand-` did the trick.  very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `background-attachement:fixed` so simply add the same background to the navbar with a white overlay to control the opacity if needed:

```css
.navbar {
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.3),rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), 
  url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473923377535-0002805f57e8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d239ac0e409e18cf74ace503c491714f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: auto,center top;
}

.bgimg {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473923377535-0002805f57e8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d239ac0e409e18cf74ace503c491714f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid bgimg"></div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution.  Thank you. I ended up changing some of the navbar classes around ala the comments to my original post, but I can see this being a good alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set your `.bgimg` to `position: absolute;`?

Like this:

```
.bgimg {
  height: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473923377535-0002805f57e8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d239ac0e409e18cf74ace503c491714f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

Just remember to apply a higher z-index to your navbar.

See [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k4nz1b1m/)